# How to scroll immediately by a pixel offset?

Tags: gui-emacs, scroll

I was looking for a replacement to `scroll-up` / `scroll-down` that operates in pixel units.

- `pixel-scroll-mode` animates the scroll, I didn't see any functions that apply an offset directly.
- `set-window-vscroll`

  - Uses absolute position.
  - It needs the scroll to be split into pixels & characters
  - It doesn't handle moving the cursor.
  - Moving the cursor afterwards resets the scroll position.

  So it seems like it's lower level than a scroll operation.

Is there a function where you can run:

```
(scroll-down-by-pixels 40)
```

To scroll which handles constraining the point by scroll margin for eg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some constraints on pixel scrolling.

- You can't use `scroll-up` as it tags the window to reset the pixel scrolling value.
- Instead you need to use `set-window-start`, with the 3rd `NOFORCE` argument to `t`.
- This complicates things because the `point` then needs to be moved before the window, since, unlike scroll, setting the window-start doesn't move the point to stay in the window bounds.

Here is a function that handles all this.

```lisp
;; Per-line Scroll.
;; return remainder of lines to scroll (matching forward-line).
(defun my-scroll-by-lines (window lines also-move-point)
  "Line based scroll that optionally move the point.
Argument WINDOW The window to scroll.
Argument LINES The number of lines to scroll (signed).
Argument ALSO-MOVE-POINT When non-nil, move the POINT as well."
  (let ((lines-remainder 0))
    (when also-move-point
      (let ((lines-point-remainder (forward-line lines)))
        (unless (zerop lines-point-remainder)
          (setq lines (- lines lines-point-remainder)))))
    (unless (zerop lines)
      (set-window-start
        window
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (window-start))
          (setq lines-remainder (forward-line lines))
          (point))
        t)
      (when also-move-point
        (unless (zerop lines-remainder)
          (forward-line (- lines-remainder)))))
    lines-remainder))

;; Per-pixel Scroll.
;; return remainder of lines to scroll (matching forward-line).
(defun my-scroll-by-pixels (window char-height delta-px also-move-point)
  "Line based scroll that optionally move the point.
Argument WINDOW The window to scroll.
Argument CHAR-HEIGHT The result of `frame-char-height'.
Argument DELTA-PX The number of pixels to scroll (signed).
Argument ALSO-MOVE-POINT When non-nil, move the POINT as well."
  (cond
    ((< delta-px 0)
      (let*
        (
          (scroll-px-prev (- char-height (window-vscroll nil t))) ;; flip.
          (scroll-px-next (+ scroll-px-prev (- delta-px))) ;; flip.
          (lines (/ scroll-px-next char-height))
          (scroll-px (- scroll-px-next (* lines char-height)))
          (lines-remainder 0))
        (unless (zerop lines)
          (setq lines-remainder
            (- (my-scroll-by-lines window (- lines) also-move-point))) ;; flip
          (unless (zerop lines-remainder)
            (setq scroll-px char-height)))
        (set-window-vscroll window (- char-height scroll-px) t)
        (- lines-remainder)))
    ((> delta-px 0)
      (let*
        (
          (scroll-px-prev (window-vscroll nil t))
          (scroll-px-next (+ scroll-px-prev delta-px))
          (lines (/ scroll-px-next char-height))
          (scroll-px (- scroll-px-next (* lines char-height)))
          (lines-remainder 0))
        (unless (zerop lines)
          (setq lines-remainder
            (my-scroll-by-lines window lines also-move-point))
          (unless (zerop lines-remainder)
            (setq scroll-px char-height)))
        (set-window-vscroll window scroll-px t)
        lines-remainder))
    ;; no lines scrolled.
    (t 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `(require 'pixel-scroll)` and then use `pixel-scroll-pixel-up` ("*Scroll text of selected windows up AMT pixels.*") and `pixel-scroll-pixel-down` ("*Scroll text of selected windows down AMT pixels.*")?

Comment: This doesn't clamp the cursor position like regular scroll does (when scrolling up, down works), testing, sometimes it resets the scroll location in a strange way too - maybe related to the cursor being out of the view.

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in `centered-cursor-mode`:  https://github.com/emacsmirror/centered-cursor-mode

Comment: I'm writing my own mode, so depending on another mode just to clamp the cursor seems overkill. I would like to have the behavior of scroll up/down, just with pixel offsets.